# Need help with knowing when I should use $KE = \frac12mv^2$ or $V_f^2 = V_0^2 + 2ad$, in order to find final velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I'm looking at this pdf for question 15.b) and I figure out $V_f$ by using $V_f^2 = V_0^2 + 2ad$, but the answer says $W = \Delta PE = \frac12mV_f^2$, and our answers ending up totally different, can someone please explain to me whats going on?

[image: Problem 15 is the one I need help with]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $v_f^2 = v_0^2+2ad$ equation **only works under constant acceleration**.

Based on the graph, you can see that the force $F$ keeps changing, so the kinematic equation above *does not apply*, since the acceleration $a$ will not be constant.

The work-kinetic energy theorem (or conservation of energy) $W_\text{net}=\Delta \rm KE$ is true for any acceleration. And since you found out the net work (work by spring force), you can find the change in kinetic energy, and subsequently, the speed.

As a rule of thumb in intro physics, you always want to check if the problem is solvable using conservation of energy/work-KE theorem since these are very simple and easy methods compared to the alternatives.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense!